# Cannot see XAML in design view Blend 4

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, silverlight-5.0, expression-blend-4

I have installed the full Expression Blend 4 Ultimate package and I am trying to load a Silverlight 5 solution

Although the solution does load I am unable to see anything in design view

This occurs even for a straight forward "out of the box" Navigation Project

I am using VS 2010 SP1

Has anyone had this problem?

I have need mention of ensuring that the project is setup as Silverlight, and ensuring that blend 3 SDK is installed

As far as I can tell, both of these apply

Paul

Answer (score 3):

A Silverlight 5 Solution will not load in Expression Blend 4.

You will need to download the Expression Blend 5 Preview:

[www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9503](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9503)

Please note that it has some bugs which can affect your views, mainly around creating design instances from viewmodels.